# How to adjust brightness in games with Radeon driver?

Tags: graphics, brightness, radeon

I recently installed Lubuntu 12.10 on an older laptop, an HP Pavilion zv6000. It runs GREAT with one exception. I am unable to adjust the brightness in any games.

I realize I am stuck using the open source Radeon driver with this card, the **Mobility Radeon Xpress 200Mm** but I was wondering if there was any way to get it so I can adjust brightness in games. I really wish companies would support their older hardware better as older hardware can benefit the most from Lubuntu.

Any help is appreciated, I don't want to have to go back to XP, but I do like playing low-spec games like OpenArena on this machine!